# Random function not found error in sp-core::H256 Substrate

Tags: rust, hash, blockchain, substrate, parity-io

I am facing a strange error in transaction restructuring, `sp-core 4.0.0-dev` don't seem to have random() function. Here is the crate [reference](https://docs.rs/sp-core/latest/sp_core/struct.H256.html#method.random). Can anybody take a look and share some insight?

[image: error]

[image: usage]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: More info here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/sp-corehashh256random-not-found